# Aligning rectangles around the inside of a circle and rotate

Tags: php, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a program that generates an image.

It places `x` images around a circle with `x` circumference.

See below output of the current implementation.
 [image: Current implementation example]

I need all of the rectangles to be inside of the circle and to be evenly placed.

Note that on the image above, the current implementation, some of the rectangles are on the inside and some are on the outside.

I'm unsure what is wrong with my calculation, please see below code for placing the rectangles.

```
 /**
 * Draw the points around a circle
 * @param  $count
 * @param  $circumference
 */
public function drawWheel($count, $circumference)
{
    /**
     * The starting angle
     */
    $angle = 0;

    /**
     * The starting step between rectangles
     */
    $step = (2 * pi()) / $count;

    /**
     * The center X of the canvas
     */
    $startX = ($this->canvas['width'] / 2);

    /**
     * The center Y of the canvas
     */
    $startY = ($this->canvas['height'] / 2);


    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        /**
         * Width of rectangle
         */
        $width = 85;

        /**
         * Height of rectangle
         */
        $height = 41;

        /**
         * Rectangle X position
         */
        $x = ($startX + ($circumference / 2) * cos($angle)) - $width / 2;

        /**
         * Rectangle Y position
         */
        $y = ($startY + ($circumference / 2) * sin($angle)) - $height / 2;

        /**
         * Degrees to rotate the rectangle around the circle
         */
        $rotateAngle = atan2((($startX - ($width / 2)) - $x), (($startY - ($height)) - $y)) * 180 / pi();

        /**
         * The rectangle image
         */
        $watermark = Image::make(base_path('test.png'));

        $watermark->opacity(75);
        $watermark->resize($width, $height);
        $watermark->rotate($rotateAngle);

        $this->image->insert($watermark, 'top-left', ceil($x), ceil($y));

        /**
         * Increment the angle
         */
        $angle += $step;
    }
}
```

The part of the function that makes the calculations is below.

```
$x = ($startX + ($circumference / 2) * cos($angle)) - $width / 2;

$y = ($startY + ($circumference / 2) * sin($angle)) - $height / 2;

$rotateAngle = atan2((($startX - ($width / 2)) - $x), (($startY - ($height)) - $y)) * 180 / pi();
```

The rotation point is the center of the rectangle.

Image is rotated using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Circle is drawn using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledarc.php

Comment: did you try with dots ? It may come from the "css" rectangle rotation.

Comment: Try with dots? Not sure I understand. There is no "css" used, this is an image generated by PHP.

Comment: sorry i was concerned about css questions, are you sure that the rotation center is the center of your rectangle("test.png") ?

Comment: How does `watermark->rotate` work? What is rotation center?

Comment: @MBo http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php "The center of rotation is the center of the image, and the rotated image may have different dimensions than the original image."

Comment: @CharliePrynn Ok, so center calculation seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width/height will be flipped once the rectangle is rotated, this is something I did not factor in.

MBo's answer helped with the main x,y and rotation coordinates.

See amended code below.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $width = 85;
            $height = 41;

            $x = ($startX + (($circumference - $height) / 2) * cos($angle));
            $y = ($startY + (($circumference - $height) / 2) * sin($angle));

            $rotateAngle = 90 - $angle * 180 / pi(); 

            $watermark = Image::make(base_path('test.png'));

            $watermark->opacity(75);
            $watermark->resize($width, $height);
            $watermark->rotate($rotateAngle);

            $this->image->insert($watermark, 'top-left', ceil($x - ($watermark->width() / 2)), ceil($y - ($watermark->height() / 2)));

            $this->drawCircle($x, $y, 10);
            $this->drawCircle($x, $y, 10);


            $angle += $step;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines are suspicious:

```
$x = ($startX + ($circumference / 2) * cos($angle)) - $width / 2;
$y = ($startY + ($circumference / 2) * sin($angle)) - $height / 2;
```

To place rectangle center inside the circle at inner radius, you have to use something like this:

```
$x = ($startX + (($circumference - $height) / 2) * cos($angle));
$y = ($startY + (($circumference - $height) / 2) * sin($angle));
```

And rotation angle is simply

```
$rotateAngle = $angle * 180 / Pi - 90; // probably $angle+90 depending on coordinate system
```

Rotated watermark has bounding rectangle with dimensions

```
Fi = rotateAngle * Pi / 80 
New_Height = $width * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + $height * Abs(Cos(Fi))
New_Width = $width * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + $height * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

Correct $x and $y for right output:

```
$x = $x - New_Width/2
$y = $y - New_Height/2
```

Comment: Using your new calculations, please see the updated image generated: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9O025.jpg

Comment: What is `circumference` here? I considered it as diameter. How is the circle drawn? Have you used expression for $rotateAngle (I've added it later)?

Comment: Oh, I caught! Left top corner of every rectangle is on the place for the center!

Comment: The circumference is 700. The circle is drawn using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledellipse.php And yeah, used the new rotateAngle calculation. Tried plus and minus, both give unexpected results.

Comment: Not sure I understand your second comment! Sorry.

Comment: OK. Draw small dots at calculated $x, $y. They are centers of watermark rectangles. Right?  Now- how to draw rectangle with this center? (I am not familiar with GD functions' pecularities)

Comment: Ok, so I have draw small dots at the $x and $y after they've been calculated. See results: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dRSqo.jpg

Comment: OK. Centers are good. Now about rotation - I missed that rotation angle in degrees - change Pi/2 to 90. And what about 'top-left' parameter of `insert` - are there another values possible?

Comment: The other options for `insert` can be seen here: http://image.intervention.io/api/insert top-left is 0,0 of the entire canvas. Current output with new rotateAngle looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgdbi.jpg

Comment: Use 'center' option. Another rad/deg confusion - use $angle * 180 / Pi + 90

Comment: Using the option 'center' and new $rotateAngle = http://i.stack.imgur.com/TrEL4.jpg

Comment: Hmm, this option is for main canvas origin. Change sign to minus $angle * 180 / Pi - 90

Comment: OK.  Reverse angle: 90 - $angle * 180 / Pi

Comment: Reversed and it seems better, although still not centered within the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MMJQY.jpg

Comment: I'm so sorry about this - See updated image produced when using the code in the updated answer -http://i.stack.imgur.com/ahvWJ.jpg

Comment: Small circles drawn using non corrected X and Y: http://i.stack.imgur.com/grE6A.jpg

Comment: Try to exchange New_Width and New_Height.This process looks like dumb guessing - you have to debug and check all calculated values for some angles.

Comment: You don't use New_Width (width of bounding rectangle) in your code with `insert`?